# newest raspbian missing wpa_supplicant.conf

Tags: raspbian, wifi, wpa, wpa-supplicant

With the newest raspbian running on a CM4, I am unable to find any SSID or passphrase in `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` and thus am unable to change the wifi password by mounting the SD card on my computer.
The WiFi is working though, without the SSID being present in wpa_supplicant.conf...
I can also configure the wifi using wpa_cli, but that does not seem to make any changes to wpa_supplicant.conf.

The OS reports as "Debian 1:6.1.63-1+rpt1", Debian Bookworm.

Here is my question:
Where is the WIFI password and SSID stored and how do I access that file with the SD card and a computer, withouth booting up the PI?

Comment: Looks like a case of failing to read the documentation.

Comment: Added some information. What documentation did I miss to read?

Comment: Is that sufficient?

Comment: Just re-read your question & realized my answer missed the mark. You asked how to get to the wifi password without booting the pi. That's not the question that was answered - at least initially. As it turns out, **you can no longer access your wifi password without booting up***... at least not easily, like in the good old days. Anyway, +1 and I've edited my answer FWIW.

Comment: True, because I noticed that it didn't reflect my true question.

Comment: @Milliways: The question is in the last sentence in the post. It **never changed** across 3 revisions. But don't take my word for it - check it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

> With the newest raspbian running on a ...

"newest raspbian" sounds like 'bookworm', and in 'bookworm' the application `nmcli` (or `nmtui` if you have a GUI bent) has *"taken over the host/client networking function"*.

The blog titled ["How to Connect to Wi-Fi Through the Linux Terminal With Nmcli"](https://www.makeuseof.com/connect-to-wifi-with-nmcli/) should get you going.

Beyond that, learning to use the "Official Documentation" may save you a few trips to SE (and the verbal abuse that goes along with not having done your homework :) For example, having a question related to *"wifi password"*:

1. go to [RPi official documentation](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/)
2. enter 'wifi password' in the box, and select one of the "suggestions". after doing so, you may eventually come to this section on [*Connect to a wireless network*](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/configuration.html#connect-to-a-wireless-network) where you will find this:

> Previous versions of Raspberry Pi OS made use of a wpa_supplicant.conf file which could be placed into the boot folder to configure wireless network settings. This is no longer possible from Raspberry Pi OS Bookworm onwards.

And so - you were a *victim* of your own experience! This is one of the things I dislike about all the suck-y new s**t  :) lol

Comment: `nmcli` ... or `nmtui` for a slightly easier experience

Answer (score 1):

It appears you have installed some version of Bookworm.

All new OS releases have details explaining the nature of the changes
https://www.raspberrypi.com/news/bookworm-the-new-version-of-raspberry-pi-os/

Bookworm (by default) uses `Network Manager` which does NOT use wpa_supplicant.conf although my *Raspberry Pi OS Bookworm* 64bit has the file `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` it is empty

There is extensive documentation on Configuring Networking
https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/configuration.html#configuring-networking

It is still not clear which particular version you installed and the best approach depends on this (normally only the 64bit identifies itself as *Debian*).
If you have installed Desktop use the networking icon on the panel.
If you have installed *Raspberry Pi OS Lite* there is a similar Curses menu which can be run at the command line with  `nmtui` which presents a similar menu.

It is also possible to configure at command line with `nmcli` but this is more complex.

If you want to know about NetworkManager there are many posts documenting this in addition to the link above e.g. https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/139795/8697 which shows
each WiFi network has a separate config file in `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/` although in a well configured system these will have a 256bit WPA PSK rather than an ASCII passphrase. These files COULD be edited off line, but it is difficult to see WHY you would want to do this.